# ModSecurity: How to 'exec' based on 'severity' level?

Tags: mod-security, mod-security2

I am using mod_security 2.6.3, and I would like to be able to execute a shell script based on a rule-severity level. I am using the core rule set (CRS), which sets the severity level to 2 (for 'critical') when an attack is detected.

I would like to execute my script whenever the severity is high enough.

I tried to use the `SecDefaultAction` setting, such as:

```
SecDefaultAction "phase:2,log,deny,status:403,exec:/path/to/my/script"
```

But since the 'exec' action is a "non-disruptive" one, it always get executed, whether a critical rule or a non-critical rule is trigerred.

I could go through each critical `SecRule` and add "exec" next to it, but that would be tedious (and repetitive, and ugly).

I thought I could do something like:

```
SecRule ENV:SEVERITY "@lt 4" "exec:/path/to/my/script"
```

But somehow it never gets executed, probably because the critical rules have a block or deny statement which stops rule processing (since considered disruptive).

I also tried using the CRS anomaly score feature, like this:

```
SecRule TX:ANOMALY_SCORE "@ge 4" "exec:/path/to/my/script"
```

But it still does not get processed.
Any idea on how I could do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [HIGHEST_SEVERITY](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/mod-security/index.php?title=Reference_Manual#HIGHEST_SEVERITY) variable to test it, such as:

```
SecRule HIGHEST_SEVERITY "@le 5" "nolog,pass,exec:/path/to/your/script"
```

Note the `nolog,pass` additional parameters that will preserve the original log message from the rule that changed the severity level.

Also, I suggest that you place this condition early in your .conf file (e.g. just after your `SecDefaultAction` line) to ensure it gets included in all contexts.

Another way of doing it would be to use a custom HTTP response status code in your SecDefaultAction (for instance, 418 "I'm a teapot") and trigger your condition based on it, in the logging phase (once the default action has been processed):

```
# On error, log then deny request with "418 I'm a teapot":
SecDefaultAction "phase:2,log,deny,status:418"

# On HTTP response status code 418, execute your script:
SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "^418$" "phase:5,nolog,pass,exec:/path/to/your/script"
```

Comment: When i try your code, getting this error: 
ModSecurity: No action id present within the rule. Edit: used this code: SecRule HIGHEST_SEVERITY "@le 5" "id:'290090',nolog,pass,exec:/usr/bin/pngquant".. Just added an id